# Graph does not support transactions

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I've tried two transactional cases on gremlin-java.

**First** case:

```
@Bean
public Cluster gremlinCluster()
{
    return Cluster.build()
            .addContactPoint(GREMLIN_ENDPOINT)
            .port(GREMLIN_PORT)
            .enableSsl(GREMLIN_SSL_ENABLED)
            .create();
} 
...
@Bean
public GraphTraversalSource gremlinGraph(Cluster gremlinCluster)
{
    return traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(gremlinCluster, "g"));
}
...
GraphTraversalSource graph;
...

final Transaction tx = graph.tx();
...
```

It gives error: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Graph does not support transactions`

**Second** Case:

```
    String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Client client = cluster.connect(sessionId);
    client.submit("g.addV('App').property('appId', 1)");
    client.submit("graph error query");
    client.close();
    ...
    graph.V().has("App", "appId", 1).next(); => It gives value
```

In second case, Expected situation is:

1. rollback will work.
2. return no-result from `graph.V().has("App", "appId", 1).next();`.

However, rollback doesn't work.

Is there any suggestion? How can I achieve transaction on gremlin-java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first case, I would ask, what graph database are you using? For example, if `graph` is a TinkerGraph then you can expect that error as it simply doesn't support them:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> graph.features().graph().supportsTransactions()
==>false
gremlin> g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using("localhost",8182,"g"))
==>graphtraversalsource[emptygraph[empty], standard]
gremlin> g.graph
==>emptygraph[empty]
gremlin> g.graph.features().graph().supportsTransactions()
==>false
```

For your second case, you are sending scripts in a session. If you are using a graph that doesn't support transactions (i.e. the same graph that is giving you the error in the first case) then I would suspect that your change was effectively committed on execution of the first request as there is no transaction to open or close. Of course, it is worth noting that for graphs that do support transactions, you can have per-request auto-commit functionality with session-managed transactions described in this [section](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sessions).

You might find this [entire section](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#transactions) of the Reference Documentation helpful in understanding the various modes of transactions in different usage contexts.

Comment: graph: GraphTraversalSource

Comment: stephen, I've edited my question. (cluster and graph...)

Comment: you are connecting remotely which means the local graph instance is "empty" - see my updated example code in my answer. the question of your "graph" and its support of transactions is therefore more related to the graph you are connecting to. i again suggest that you read the entire section of the Reference Documentation that I linked to on the various modes of transactions. it will clarify my answer considerably.